# Normalize age frequency data for PCA

Tags: pca, normalization, dimensionality-reduction, standardization

I am working on a project to forecast house ownership rates. One dataset I have consists of number of people of each age from 1-99 per geographic area code. For example, 20 people aged 1, 59 people aged 2, ... 5 people aged 99.

The dimensionality of this data seems quite too large to use unprocessed, and so I was thinking of applying PCA to reduce it down. In this scenario, should I be standardising my data in any way, given it is frequency data?

For what it's worth, a normal distribution is not a good approximation (far more individuals aged 1 than 99). I'd also appreciate any better ideas if PCA is the wrong approach to this!

Comment: Why not just use total population -- or other subtotals relevant to your underlying problem? PCA here just takes you away from the data. The components won't be easier to think about than the original variables.

Comment: Distribution across variables is of little or no relevance here. It's the correlations or covanances between variables that drive PCs.

Comment: Just realised I said "occupancy" when I meant "ownership" rates - edited now! People 0-18 for instance are less likely to own a house than 65+.

Comment: Selected percentiles, such as 10, 25, 50, 75, 90% points of each age distribution could be good predictors.

Comment: Summarization by PCA of ownership by year of age doesn't seem helpful or easily interpretable. Ownership is a characteristic of the life course that usually lasts for years and varies by broad categories, eg, 20-30, 30-50, etc, and also depends on family composition.

Comment: Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet, but I am completely confused. What would you be doing PCA on?  You seem to have one variable: Age.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have age frequency. It's a table with columns 1-99, and rows with number of people of each age within a region. I can't put 100 variables directly into a model, and many of the age frequencies are correlated.